# filter mapping for particular url

Tags: java, xml, jsp, filter, servlet-filters

ExpiryFilter.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class ExpiryFilter implements Filter {

    // add a five years expiry
    private Integer years = 1;

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (years > -1) {
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.setTime(new Date());
            c.add(Calendar.YEAR, years);

            // HTTP header date format: Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT
            String o = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz")
                    .format(c.getTime());
            ((HttpServletResponse) response).setHeader("Expires", o);
        }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {      
    }
}
```

I am creating one web application in that i want to give validity time period. So am using filter for mapping.

web.xml

```
<filter>
    <description>Set cache expiry for static content</description>
    <filter-name>ExpiryFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>ExpiryFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ExpiryFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/ExpiryDate/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

This is my local host link`http://localhost:8080/ExpiryDate/test.jsp.` I need to filter after one year. After one year or particular time period that particular link could not be run.So please help me to find out the solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it is a one page just make your check for the difference the two dates (a starting date that you specify and the date of the request ) in the start of your JSP page 
to be something like this peso do code

```
if (difference is one year ){
<body>
link is expired
</body>
}else{
<body>
//what ever data you show
</body>
}
```

Comment: it expires correct only when i map <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern> but it expires everything like gmail etc so i need that particular url only so please guide me the codings or show me the links

Comment: of course it will expire every request to the URL pattern ,so do you mean you want just one page to be expired?

Comment: yeah absolutely http://localhost:8080/ExpiryDate/test.jsp this particular link i want to expire

Comment: see my updated answer no need for a filter in this case

Comment: then also the problem will come know after one year the every link will get expired knw. I need that particular url only if we use if else then also the same prob will come knw

Comment: if you use the filter it will be for every page but if you use the if else it will be just for the url that calling the page only

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61662/discussion-between-anand-and-dunken).